# A valid schema couldn't be composed. The following composition errors were found in @apollo/gateway

Tags: apollo-server, apollo-gateway

I am using below latest versions & migrating to @apollo/server v4

```
 "@apollo/gateway": "2.4.8",  
  "@apollo/server": "4.7.4",  
  "graphql": "16.6.0",  
  "type-graphql": "1.1.1",
```

Rest other errors solved but now getting the below error, do anyone have idea, I searched a lot but not getting what I am missing.

below is code snippet,

```
import { ApolloGateway, IntrospectAndCompose, RemoteGraphQLDataSource } from '@apollo/gateway';

class AuthenticatedDataSource extends RemoteGraphQLDataSource {
  willSendRequest({ request, context }) {
    // Pass the user's id from the context to underlying services
    // as a header called `user-id`    
  }
}
const gateway = new ApolloGateway({
  supergraphSdl: new IntrospectAndCompose({
    subgraphs: [
      { name: "userService", url: "http://localhost:4001" }
    ]
  }),
  buildService({ name, url }) {
    return new AuthenticatedDataSource({ url });
  },
});
```

& my node version is : 18.13.0 & npm 8.19.3

but getting below error,

```
error:  Error: A valid schema couldn't be composed. The following composition errors were found:
Invalid definition for directive "@tag": "@tag" should have locations FIELD_DEFINITION, OBJECT, INTERFACE, UNION, ARGUMENT_DEFINITION, SCALAR, ENUM, ENUM_VALUE, INPUT_OBJECT, INPUT_FIELD_DEFINITION, but found (non-subset) FIELD_DEFINITION, OBJECT, INTERFACE, UNION, ARGUMENT_DEFINITION, SCALAR, ENUM, ENUM_VALUE, INPUT_OBJECT, INPUT_FIELD_DEFINITION, SCHEMA
  at IntrospectAndCompose.createSupergraphFromSubgraphList (/home/node/app/node_modules/@apollo/gateway/src/supergraphManagers/IntrospectAndCompose/index.ts:118:13)
  at IntrospectAndCompose.updateSupergraphSdl (/home/node/app/node_modules/@apollo/gateway/src/supergraphManagers/IntrospectAndCompose/index.ts:106:32)
  at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
  at async IntrospectAndCompose.initialize (/home/node/app/node_modules/@apollo/gateway/src/supergraphManagers/IntrospectAndCompose/index.ts:62:30)
  at async ApolloGateway.initializeSupergraphManager (/home/node/app/node_modules/@apollo/gateway/src/index.ts:394:22)
  at async ApolloGateway.load (/home/node/app/node_modules/@apollo/gateway/src/index.ts:304:7)
```